# javascript/jquery incrementation check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very delicate problem, I'll make an example. What am i doing is that I'm basically prepending elements and differentiating them by incrementing (i need to do it this way for certain reasons), then there is an option to click on any element and delete it.

This is only stupid example of what it looks like:

```js
    $(function () {
    var i = 0;
        $("#new").click(function(){
            i++;
            $("#container").prepend("<div class='prepended "+i+"'>blah blah blah</div>")


            $(".prepended").click(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="new">click here</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

When I delete any element, I need to somehow manage to make the incrementing "i" variable fill the missing element. I don't know how to explain in words so I'll explain in "code":

Let's say I prepended 6 elements so the "i" variable is now 6:

```
if(deleted_divs_class == 1)
{
    i = 1; // fill the missing "1"
    next_click_i = 6; // variable i on next click should be 6 in order to continue in right order
}
else if (deleted_divs_class !== 1 || 6) // deleted element is somewhere from middle so it's not 1 or 6
{
    i = fill_missing_number; // fill the removed number
    next_click_i = 6; // continue in right order
}
else
{ 
 i--;
 // deleted element is the last element of line so continue normally by incrementing
}
```

i know how to get deleted_divs_class variable and apply the next_click_i variable but i don't know how make the whole thing work dynamically

I know that this question might seems very weird but this is just an example, it's part of much much much bigger code and i just need to make logic of this "incrementation" in order to make the whole thing work properly as i need.

So i just can not figure out the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose I created the code you are looking for, but I’m not sure if I understood your question correctly. Look at this code. Is this what you wanted or not?

```js
    $(function () {
        var missed=[]; //Here will be stored missed numbers
        var i = 0;
        $("#new").click(function(){
            var n=0;
            if(missed.length>0) {
                n=missed.shift(); //get next missed number from the array
            } else
                n=++i;

            $("#container").prepend("<div data-i='"+n+"' class='prepended "+n+"'>"+n+"blah blah blah</div>")


        });
        $('#container').on('click',".prepended",[], function(){
                missed.push($(this).data('i')); //save removed number into missed numbers array
                $(this).remove();
          });    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="new">click here</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To backfill the deleted `i` values, you'll need to store them. In this example, `deleted_i` holds all deleted values, and attempts to retrieve the new value from there first when creating a new element. If it's empty, it defaults to incrementing the value of `i`.

Note also that the click event is now bound to the container so that it only fires once - in your example, it was getting re-bound to all `.prepended` elements, so that when you clicked on one, it was firing that function as many times as the loop had run so far.

```js
$(function () {
  var i = 0,
    deleted_i = []
    
  $("#new").click(function(){
    var idx;
    console.log(deleted_i)
    if(deleted_i.length) idx = deleted_i.shift() //grab the first deleted index, if one exists
    else idx = ++i;
    $("#container").prepend("<div data-index='"+idx+"' class='prepended "+idx+"'>blah blah blah this is "+idx+"</div>")
  });
  
  $("#container").click(function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target)
    if($target.hasClass('prepended')){
      $target.remove();
      deleted_i.push($target.attr('data-index'))
    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="new">click here</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
```